# Any additional setup needed for @ControllerAdvice to work with an ExceptionHandler class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have the following global exception handler class:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler(value = ResourceAccessException.class)
   public ResponseEntity<Object> handleTimeout(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
      return handleExceptionInternal(ex, "body", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, request);
   }

}
```

However running tests on it shows that it doesn't seem to be outputting anything when an exception is fired. Does this class need to be at a certain level in the project hierarchy?

Either I am just firing exceptions incorrectly in my test or I need to do some additional setup. Most documentation I've come across only refers to creating the class listed above though.

Test File:

```
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
class MyGlobalExceptionHandlerTest{

   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @MockBean
   private MyController myController;

   @MockBean 
   private MyFacade myFacade;

   @Test
   void shouldThrow() {
      when(myFacade.getRows(any())).thenThrow(ResourceAccessException.class);
      this.mockMvc.perform(post("/s")
          .content(/*content*/)
          .contentType(/*contentType*/)
          .andExpect(status().isRequestTimeout());
   }
```

Apologies if anything doesn't make sense or looks odd. I'm still wrapping my head around Spring as a whole and have been borrowing from existing files in the project. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I recommend never using `standaloneSetup` for tests; it is extremely easy to introduce important differences between the test and production configurations. If you're going to use MockMvc, autowire it; you're already doing that, and then replacing it, so just kill your `setup` method (and I recommend using full `@SpringBootTest` to ensure that configuration differences don't creep in).